# Converting Formatted String into a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have a String that is formatted like a 2D array like this:

```
"[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]"
```

How can I get the program to read the string as an actual 2D array like this

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

so that I can perform matrix calculations?

I've tried removing the commas and brackets and then converting the string numbers to integer numbers but that does not work because I need to keep the shape of the 2D array. In this example, I would need the final 2D array to be size **[4][4]**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [4]: import ast                                                                                                                                                              

In [5]: array = "[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]"                                                                                                      

In [6]: array = ast.literal_eval(array)                                                                                                                                         

In [7]: array                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[7]: [[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

---

> [**`ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)`**[Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)Safely evaluate an expression node or
> a string containing the following Python literal **::** strings, bytes,
> numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.

Answer (score 3):

Given that the 2D list string happens to be valid syntax for a Python 2D list, you could just use the `eval()` function:

```py
output = eval("[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]")
print(output)
print(output[0])
```

This prints:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
```